# Django QuerySet changing IN to ANY(array[...])

Tags: django, postgresql-9.1

We've got some slow running queries in our DB and I think some of them can be solved by changing the underlying SQL.

Given the following:

```
Model.objects.filter(rel_id__in=[1,2,3])
```

Outputs (abridged):

```
SELECT all, the, fields FROM "model" WHERE ("rel_id" IN (1, 2, 2))
```

What I want is for the SQL to change to:

```
SELECT all, the, fields FROM "model" WHERE ("rel_id" = ANY(array[1, 2, 2]))
```

I know that this might be not be optimum approach, but `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` returns significantly lower figures with the second query.

So my question is, how can I get the second SQL query from my QuerySet lookup?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's weird. Please show both query plans. Usually those two would be equivalent - `IN` gets turned into `= ANY` quite early in planning IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could possibly be done like this:

```
Model.objects.extra(
    where=['"rel_id" = ANY(array%s)' % (str(your_list))]
)
```

otherwise you probably have to resort to using [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#raw).

Comment: It would be better to mention that `your_list` should be a sequence of strings to use `str.join`.

Comment: There is a caveat to this whereby your_list is a queryset or valueslist which django truncates. It should be changed to: '"feed_id" = ANY(array[%s])' % ','.join([str(ident] for ident in your_list)